# Checking the status of a sent email in django

Tags: python, django, email

I have a simple mail sending application which runs in python using Django. After sending an email is there a way to see if the recipient has opened it or is it still un-opened?
if so how can i do it?

Comment: I guess you could ask for a recipient recipe, and check if the incoming to see if it is there.  Or put a php image (php script that returns an image) in the email that looks for your site's cookie, and if found, knows that user opened the email (one of the reasons email images are blocked by default).  But other then that email doesn't support such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two ways to check that I know of are return receipts and checking to see if an image has been loaded. Neither is very reliable. I think the image one is the more reliable of the two, though.

You could take a [pluggable app for confirming a link is being clicked](https://github.com/pinax/django-email-confirmation), but instead of putting the link in the email, put an image in the email. This would require changing the [confirm_email view](https://github.com/pinax/django-email-confirmation/blob/master/emailconfirmation/views.py) to output an image (maybe an empty one).

The above library is for confirming passwords but it ought to work for checking that emails are being read, too.

Comment: I personaly in my email client and google gmail(for sure) disables images by default. Just exactly to disable this oportunity... So better is to be honest... IMHO

Comment: I have never clicked a return receipt in the last year (or been asked to), but I often let images be displayed if it's email that I wanted to receive. So anecdotally, I think it's the better option of the two.

Answer (score 3):

You can try setting **require return receipt flag** on the email you are sending. But, a lot of people (I know I do) ignore that return receipt so you will never find out in those cases.

If you are asking for a 100% certain method of finding out if the recipient read his/her email, then the straight answer is: **NO**, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have no other way than generate confirm url in your message like most sites registrations do. If person would be glad to register on your website, he will certainly click confirm at his email client of any sort. Otherwise it's a spam/scam email.

There is no way you can do it and know it's a live e-mail for sure...

Besides there are 2 other ways mentioned by my colleagues... But they are based on "unsecure" settings in old email clients rather than sure way... IMHO.